# Solaris 10 port forwarding

Tags: solaris-10

I am trying to setup Apache using another port instead of port 80. I use ipfnat to accomplish the redirection of ports so that the external world would still think that it is running on port 80.

/etc/ipf/ipfnat.conf rdr 0.0.0.0/0 port 80 -> port 7000

This seems to work fine from the internet but when i go to localhost the port redirection seem not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ipfilter need to be use for this purpose.

loopback forwarding should be enabled